# Name generator verbose code; looking for concise & nice solutions

Tags: python, algorithm, input

The following code works if user input is less than 6, but even as a beginner I don't think this is the correct way to do it, is there any concise and pretty solution for this?

code description: For example, user enters `4 v v v v`,  this name generator will generate a names with four vowels 20 times.

```
import random, string

vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

nameLenInput = int(input("how long do you wanna the name to be? max 6 characters"))
if nameLenInput == 6:
    letter_input_1=input("what letter do you want for 1st cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_2=input("what letter do you want for 2nd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_3=input("what letter do you want for 3rd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_4=input("what letter do you want for 4th cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_5=input("what letter do you want for 5th cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_6=input("what letter do you want for 6th cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
elif nameLenInput == 5:
    letter_input_1 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 1st cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_2 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 2nd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_3 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 3rd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_4 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 4th cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_5 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 5th cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")

elif nameLenInput == 4:
    letter_input_1 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 1st cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_2 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 2nd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_3 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 3rd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_4 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 4th cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")

elif nameLenInput == 3:
    letter_input_1 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 1st cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_2 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 2nd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_3 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 3rd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")

elif nameLenInput == 2:
    letter_input_1 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 1st cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")
    letter_input_2 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 2nd cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")

elif nameLenInput == 1:
    letter_input_1 = input(
        "what letter do you want for 1st cha? Enter 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonants, 'l' for any letter: ")

def generator():
        if letter_input_1=="v":
            letter1=random.choice(vowels)

        elif letter_input_1=="c":
            letter1=random.choice(consonants)

        elif letter_input_1=="l":
            letter1=random.choice(letters)

        else:
            letter1=letter_input_1
        if nameLenInput == 1:
            name = letter1
            return name

        if letter_input_2=="v":
            letter2=random.choice(vowels)

        elif letter_input_2=="c":
            letter2=random.choice(consonants)

        elif letter_input_2=="l":
            letter2=random.choice(letters)

        else:
            letter2=letter_input_2

        if nameLenInput == 2:
            name = letter1+letter2
            return name

        if letter_input_3=="v":
            letter3=random.choice(vowels)

        elif letter_input_3=="c":
            letter3=random.choice(consonants)

        elif letter_input_3=="l":
            letter3=random.choice(letters)

        else:
            letter3=letter_input_3

        if nameLenInput == 3:
            name = letter1 + letter2 + letter3
            return name


        if letter_input_4 == "v":
            letter4 = random.choice(vowels)

        elif letter_input_4 == "c":
            letter4 = random.choice(consonants)

        elif letter_input_4 == "l":
            letter4 = random.choice(letters)

        else:
            letter4 = letter_input_4

        if nameLenInput == 4:
            name = letter1 + letter2 + letter3 + letter4
            return name

        if letter_input_5 == "v":
            letter5 = random.choice(vowels)

        elif letter_input_5 == "c":
            letter5 = random.choice(consonants)

        elif letter_input_5 == "l":
            letter5 = random.choice(letters)

        else:
            letter5 = letter_input_5

        if nameLenInput == 5:
            name = letter1 + letter2 + letter3 + letter4 + letter5
            return name

        if letter_input_6 == "v":
            letter6 = random.choice(vowels)

        elif letter_input_6 == "c":
            letter6 = random.choice(consonants)

        elif letter_input_6 == "l":
            letter6 = random.choice(letters)

        else:
            letter6 = letter_input_6

        name=letter1+letter2+letter3+letter4
        return name

for i in range(20):
    print(generator())
```

Does the solution to make this code concise and smart has anything to do with algorithm?

Comment: `for` loops seem the most obvious.

Comment: Why not ask the user to enter a string such as `"cvvlvc"` and construct that random name simply from that input? No need to pester the user on a character by character basis.

Comment: Please quit using bold on your entire question.

Comment: can you please be more specific? like full code that works? i'm pretty good at  processing code xD.

Comment: I am hesitant to give full code for something which seems like homework.

Comment: my current college does not even teach python, i promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for concise, you could do something like this:

```
import random

vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
letters = vowels + consonants

#dictionary to associate letter codes with letter sets:
d = {'v':vowels, 'c':consonants, 'l':letters}

s = input("""Enter a string such as "vcllvc" which indicates
where you would like vowels, consonants,
and unrestricted letters to be: """)

for i in range(20):
    name = ''.join(random.choice(d[t])for t in s)
    print(name)
```

Typical run:

```
Enter a string such as "vcllvc" which indicates
where you would like vowels, consonants,
and unrestricted letters to be: clvccvl
nfusjoo
tzofkuf
vnihtut
vqarvoi
hyisxaj
hsaxcef
daobdai
byewkar
vlaznic
mbomsuw
mauhkic
rhumbea
fticmuz
ciacfof
zgezdak
mdahwed
jcavtam
tnofmeu
baowkeg
miedpuh
```

Comment: incredible, no way i was expecting 9 lines of code, still processing....

Comment: how do you do this line of code in separate lines? `name = ''.join(random.choice(d[t])for t in s)`

Comment: don't know where do i put `''.join` in separate lines, the console always print one letter at a time,

Comment: @Z.Q Not quite sure what you are asking `''.join()` will join together the strings in any iterable contained inside the `()`. As a hint, the expression  `''.join(random.choice(d[t])for t in s)` is functionally equivalent to `''.join(listOfChars)` where `listOfChars = [random.choice(d[t])for t in s]` (though the former is more memory-efficient than the latter). Read up on list comprehensions so that you can produce a list with the desired characters and then join the list. Once you get comfortable with such a 2-line approach, skip the part of first creating the list and just use a join.

Comment: i understand what this line does `name = ''.join(random.choice(d[t])for t in s)`, i learned list comprehension, but it's a little too concise, i wonder how to do it in separate lines, i crated a list but it only works on single character input, when i try to put something like vv, it gave me this KeyError "vv"

Comment: i got it! `for i in range(20):
    li=[]
    for p in s:
        li.append(random.choice(d[p]))
    name=str().join(li)
    print(name)`

Comment: @Z.Q, 

The comment you just posted works by building an empty list and adding elements on one at a time. It works, but it's not as clean as the list comprehension solution.

A list comprehension is a useful way to build a sequence based on another sequence-- think of it like a pipeline. You're transforming the source list (list of characters like "vvllc" into an output list (like "aejrp"). It's providing a path for data to flow through.

They both work, but list comprehensions are definitely worth learning about. They make a lot of problems easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random, string

vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

nameLenInput = int(input("Enter the length of name: "))

selectedLetters = []
for x in range(nameLenInput):
    l = input("What letter you want for % cha? 'v' for vowel, 'c' for consonant, 'l' for any letter: "%(x+1))
    selectedLetters.append(l)

def generate():
    generated = ''

    for letter in selectedLetters:
        if letter=='v':
            generated+=random.choice(vowels)
        elif letter=='c':
            generated+=random.choice(consonants)
        elif letter=='l':
            generated+=random.choice(letters)
    return generated


for i in range(20):
    print(generate())
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it has an error that says raw_input is not defined....I've only used python 3, is that a python 2 thing?